# Adding 'Go back to news' link to single post

Tags: php, wordpress, anchor

I am trying to add a simple link, which goes back to the news (Archive) site from single post. But what I want is to go back to the anchor from the present post.

So instead of:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/news">Go back</a>
```

I need:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/news#post-1111">Go back</a>
```

I want totadd it to single-content.php, so how can I create it in php?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have post id somewhere in your php file.

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/news#post-<?php echo $post_id; ?>">Go back</a>
```

like this sample url:
http://example.com/post?id=1

```
<?php

$post_id = $_GET['id'];

?>

<a href="http://www.example.com/news#post-<?php echo $post_id; ?>">Go back</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this

**$post_id** is your current post id.

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/news#post-<?php echo $post_id; ?>">Go back</a>
```